# remove white spaces below winforms graph

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have created a chart in winforms and host it in WPF using winformhost. When I am implementing this in wpf, there is a space below my graph. If I reduce the size of chart, chart becomes small. How to remove that space below the graph?

Here is my code.

**XAML.cs**

```
var chartArea = new ChartArea("EQGraph");

Chart chart1 = this.FindName("EQGraph") as Chart;
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("EQGraph");

chart1.Series.Add("Front Left");

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 20000;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 20;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -50;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Frequency(Hz)";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Gain";

int[] xValuesFrontLeft = { 10, 100, 1000, 5000, 4200, 8499 };
int[] yValuesFrontLeft = { 16, 10, -5, -10, 35, -40 };
chart1.Series["Front Left"].Points.DataBindXY(xValuesFrontLeft, yValuesFrontLeft);

chart1.Series["Front Left"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
```

**XAML**

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="9" Background="#FFFBF9F9">

  <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" Height="500">
    <winformchart:Chart x:Name="EQGraph" Dock="Fill">
      <winformchart:Chart.Series >
        <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
      </winformchart:Chart.Series>
      <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
        <winformchart:ChartArea/>
      </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
    </winformchart:Chart>
  </WindowsFormsHost>

</DockPanel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to create new `ChartArea` to place your graph, because your graph is placed inside `WindowsFormsHost` in XAML already, and it's docked, so it will be the same size as it's host. Use that chart like this:

```
// Remove these lines
// var chartArea = new ChartArea("EQGraph");
// Chart chart1 = this.FindName("EQGraph") as Chart;
// chart1.ChartAreas.Add("EQGraph");

// Now you will be adding values, series and properties to your graph inside WinFormsHost
Chart chart1 = EQGraph;
```

You could also replace `chart1` with `EQGraph` inside your code directly, at all places:

```
EQGraph.Series.Add("Front Left");

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 20000;
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 10;
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 20;
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -50;
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Frequency(Hz)";
EQGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Gain";

int[] xValuesFrontLeft = { 10, 100, 1000, 5000, 4200, 8499 };
int[] yValuesFrontLeft = { 16, 10, -5, -10, 35, -40 };
EQGraph.Series["Front Left"].Points.DataBindXY(xValuesFrontLeft, yValuesFrontLeft);

EQGraph.Series["Front Left"].ChartType =SeriesChartType.Spline;
```